# Experimental constraints on dark matter pressure?

Tags: cosmology, experimental-physics, pressure, dark-matter

The $\Lambda$CDM model assumes collisionless dark matter, so that its pressure $P=0$. But what are the best experimental constraints on $P$? I guess on $P/\rho$ in fact…

Comment: Doesn't matter in cosmology have, by definition, $P = 0$?

Comment: Not in the early universe.